# pandas datetime index drop duplicates keep row with specific column max value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time                                val1    val2
2020-09-21 00:33:29.226000-05:00    0.115   98.5
2020-09-21 01:56:49.225000-05:00    0.557   141.9
**2020-09-21 02:46:05.659000-05:00  0.046   39.4**
**2020-09-21 02:46:05.659000-05:00  0.174   305.2**
2020-09-21 03:45:19.899000-05:00    0.118   161.1
2020-09-21 04:33:25.532000-05:00    0.145   182.6
2020-09-21 05:09:12.862000-05:00    0.343   139.5
2020-09-21 06:07:50.445000-05:00    2.036   44.7
**2020-09-20 07:59:30.475000-05:00  0.082   10.8**
**2020-09-20 07:59:30.475000-05:00  0.092   19**
2020-09-20 08:01:51.487000-05:00    0.083   18.8
2020-09-20 09:56:00.108000-05:00    1.058   9.5
2020-09-20 11:21:26.805000-05:00    0.514   9
2020-09-20 12:28:08.667000-05:00    0.242   16.2
2020-09-20 13:29:31.026000-05:00    0.115   56.8
2020-09-20 14:04:17.509000-05:00    0.067   135.9
2020-09-20 15:59:42.175000-05:00    0.153   169.3
2020-09-20 16:11:05.711000-05:00    0.128   107
2020-09-20 17:24:43.678000-05:00    0.157   122.1
2020-09-20 18:02:01.091000-05:00    0.152   103.6
2020-09-20 19:32:09.288000-05:00    0.164   118
2020-09-20 20:50:39.238000-05:00    0.106   120.5
2020-09-20 21:04:13.440000-05:00    0.125   133.4
2020-09-20 22:57:49.545000-05:00    0.206   94.1
2020-09-20 23:54:57.790000-05:00    0.16    95.5
```

this dataframe is create from a bigger one with this line of code `df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.hour)['val2'].idxmax()]`, the problem is that it keeps some duplicate hours `2020-09-21 02:46:05.659000-05:00` and  `2020-09-20 07:59:30.475000-05:00` and I would like to keep the rows with the max value for the val2 column to have this result:

```
Time                                val1    val2
2020-09-21 00:33:29.226000-05:00    0.115   98.5
2020-09-21 01:56:49.225000-05:00    0.557   141.9
**2020-09-21 02:46:05.659000-05:00  0.174   305.2**
2020-09-21 03:45:19.899000-05:00    0.118   161.1
2020-09-21 04:33:25.532000-05:00    0.145   182.6
2020-09-21 05:09:12.862000-05:00    0.343   139.5
2020-09-21 06:07:50.445000-05:00    2.036   44.7
**2020-09-20 07:59:30.475000-05:00  0.092   19**
2020-09-20 08:01:51.487000-05:00    0.083   18.8
2020-09-20 09:56:00.108000-05:00    1.058   9.5
2020-09-20 11:21:26.805000-05:00    0.514   9
2020-09-20 12:28:08.667000-05:00    0.242   16.2
2020-09-20 13:29:31.026000-05:00    0.115   56.8
2020-09-20 14:04:17.509000-05:00    0.067   135.9
2020-09-20 15:59:42.175000-05:00    0.153   169.3
2020-09-20 16:11:05.711000-05:00    0.128   107
2020-09-20 17:24:43.678000-05:00    0.157   122.1
2020-09-20 18:02:01.091000-05:00    0.152   103.6
2020-09-20 19:32:09.288000-05:00    0.164   118
2020-09-20 20:50:39.238000-05:00    0.106   120.5
2020-09-20 21:04:13.440000-05:00    0.125   133.4
2020-09-20 22:57:49.545000-05:00    0.206   94.1
2020-09-20 23:54:57.790000-05:00    0.16    95.5
```

I have tried with df2[~df2.index.duplicated()] but it drops the first or last row, not the one with the lowest value

Comment: `df2 = df2.sort_values(by='val2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='Time', keep="first")`

Comment: it works, thank you.